# XSL checkbox display checked if value is 1 from database

Tags: java, html, forms, xslt

How do I read a checkbox value in xsl?
I have a value that I read from database and based on this value this checkbox will either be check or unchecked.
I have this snipplet but the checkbox does not check even when the database_column value is 1.

```
<xsl:template.....>
     <form....>
        <input type="checkbox" id="functional_test" name="DATABASE_COLUMN">
           <xsl:if test="//DATABASE_COLUMN='1'">
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute> 
           </xsl:if>

       </input>
     </form>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT:
I also have problems retrieving the textarea values. This textarea value is actually from a select option. But when this value is retrieved it's from a database, I have no idea why the value is not appearing.
My code looks like this:

```
 <label class="control-label Mandatory" for="txtRecommendedAction"> Recommended Action*
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#modalRecommended" data-toggle="modal"> Retrieve  </button>
 </label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="txtRecommendedAction" name="recommended_action" rows="6" value="{//RECOMMENDED_ACTION}"/>
```

It just does not show the correct value in the textarea. Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: XSLT transforms a **source** tree into a **result** tree. Where is your source XML? The XPath expression you wrote above will look for a tag named <DATABASE_COLUMN> which probably contains '1'. It seems that you are trying to read the data from your result tree, which won't work.

Comment: Is the source tree from the <xsl:template> tag?
The data "DATABASE_COLUMN" comes from a servlet which retrieves from database.

Comment: If you cannot read the input XML document directly, add the following code to your stylesheet and observe the result: `<p><xsl:value-of select="//DATABASE_COLUMN"/></p>`. Then you will know what's really in there - or whether your xPath expression is actually fetching anything.

Comment: Alternatively - even preferably - run an *identity transform template* on the input. This will copy the input as is - and you can use the result as a reference for writing your stylesheet and to test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's weird to answer my own question but after researching the following code did help:

```
<xsl:element name="input">
          <xsl:attribute name="type">radio</xsl:attribute> <!-- or checkbox -->
          <xsl:attribute name="name">needModeration</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="value">true</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:if test="contains(needModeration,'true')"> <!-- just change this variable-->
              <xsl:attribute name="checked">
              </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
</xsl:element>
```

And in my html, it did check or uncheck based on the values. :D

I got the answer from this forum:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1036574.aspx

Comment: It's not weird to answer your own question. If you've managed to work out the answer for yourself then submitting (and accepting) your own answer is the right thing to do.